# translate multiple lines for a given new value - Flutter - translation

Tags: flutter

I implemented a translator for a specific outcome. My issue is that I receive an error message when I need to expand the translation reference

> Exception has occurred.
> _TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index')

working codes

```
  final translator = GoogleTranslator();

  var value1;

 void initContent() async {
    value1 = await translator.translate(
      widget.results[0]['meanings']['light'].join('\n\n'),
      to: 'fr',
    );
```

not working codes with failure

```
  final translator = GoogleTranslator();

  var value1;

  void initContent() async {
    value1 = await translator.translate(
      widget.results[0]['name']['meanings']['light'].join('\n\n'),
      to: 'fr',
    );
```

source json file

```
    "name": "Queen of Wands",
    "meanings": {
      "light": [
        "Paying close attention",
        "Helping others focus on the issue at hand",
        "Getting everyone to work together",
        "Identifying common ground",
        "Bringing people together, despite their differences",
        "Using reverse psychology"
      ],
    },
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be just `['name']` like:

```dart
    value1 = await translator.translate(
      widget.results[0]['name'],
      to: 'fr',
    );
```

Comment: Yes. I need to create multiple value on whic one has only name thanks